# Fourier Transform: Musical instruments

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

How do I Fourier Analyse the music produced by a musical instrument? What I mean is that what tools/applications are best suited to Fourier Analyse waves from musical instruments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I'm a Matlab user, here's how I would do it.  A lot of professional audio suites have Fourier analysis built in, they just call it "spectrum analysis".

1. Record the instrument using an audio recording software such as [Audacity](http://www.audacityteam.org/).  Or, you could just record a cell phone video, then use one of many applications to extract audio from cell phone videos (do a Google search to find one).
2. Export the audio as a `.wav` or `.mp3` file (at least, these are the most common).
3. Import the `.wav` file into Matlab using the [audioread](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/audioread.html) function.  This will represent your (digitized) music as a vector, where each element in the vector is a single digital sample.  For example, a `.wav` file will have 44,100 samples for every second of audio - i.e. your vector will live in $\Bbb{R}^{44,100\cdot T}$ if your audio is mono (as opposed to stereo) and $T$ seconds.  Actually, digital audio is also quantized, meaning you don't get an actual real number for each sample, but rather an integer.
4. Once you have this vector, you can then run whatever Fourier analysis you want - fft, wavelet transforms, etc.

   If you don't have Matlab, octave and python have similar packages for working with audio files (a quick Google will let you know what's out there).

Here's a quick example using Radiohead's song "Burn the Witch".  I imported it using `audioread('file.mp3')`.  This gives me a matrix $x$ that is $9728781\times 2$ (two columns because it's a stereo recording).  Here's a plot of the first second of the song - one channel is blue, the other is red.

[image]

I can do an FFT on this vector by calling $X = fft(x)$.  Here's a plot of the modulus of $X$:

[image]

Now that your song is just a vector, you can do all sorts of fun things like filter it, use it as the initial condition for a heat equation and see what the result sounds like, you dream it!

Comment: Thanks for the response. Also, could you please elaborate  on how I would use it as the initial condition for a heat equation?

Comment: @VarunPidugu it would take a while to explain.  If you search "numerical solution to heat equation" or "matlab heat equation", you can find several lecture notes on finite difference methods and even matlab code.  Many PDE books also have a chapter on this.  Basically my point was that since the music is now just a vector, you can do just about anything you want with it...